# How to loop through sql code in a querytable

Tags: sql, excel, vba, import

I want to insert certain columns in an excel spreadsheet into sql based on the value in one of the columns, i have written the sql code but when i loop through the code it keeps adding a new querytbale. is there a way to insert the value into sql refresh the querytable with the new value and insert that into the same sql table?

```
sqlString = "Insert into table(fields) select '" & ws1.Cells(row, col) & "','" & ws1.Cells(row, co2) & "','" & ws1.Cells(row, col3) & "','" & ws1.Cells(row, col4) & "','" & ws1.Cells(row, col5) & "','" & ws1.Cells(row, col6) & "'"


Set destination = ws2.Range("A1")
Set pleasework = ws2.QueryTables.Add(conString, destination, sqlString)

sqlString = "Insert into table(fields) select '" & ws1.Cells(row, col) & "','" & ws1.Cells(row, co2) & "','" & ws1.Cells(row, col3) & "','" & ws1.Cells(row, col4) & "','" & ws1.Cells(row, col5) & "','" & ws1.Cells(row, col6) & "'"

Do

With pleasework

        row = row + 1
        .CommandText = sqlString
        .Refresh
        count = count + 1

End With
Loop While count < 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can discart your code and try something like this:

```
query = INSERT INTO [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=MY_COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=MY_DATABASE].[tbMYTALBE] ([FIELD1], [FIELD2], [FIELD3]) SELECT t.FIELD1,  t.FIELD2, t.FIELD3 FROM [MY_SHEET$A1:D200] t
Call recordSet.Open(query, connection)
```

I can add the complete code if you need it